# Trying to calculate a renewal date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have a few different items with different rental periods ( 1,3,6 months to 1,3,5 years). As it stands I have a column with the last renewal date and a column indicating what is the renewal period. I wanted excel to calculate what the Renewal date would be based on the selected type of renewal. My first attempt was to convert the renewal types to some kinda of similar denomination but i got stuck trying to figure out what value/format to use.

```
Last renewal date   Renewal Type    Renewal Date    
11/11/2013           1 Year 
2/14/2014            2 Years    
8/28/2011            5 Years    
11/27/2013           3 Months
```

Comment: You can convert dates in Excel to numbers just fine, and I feel like that would push you in the direction to get what you want.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to convert "1 month" into a value? I know how to get a value of a given date, but not a general time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If by "into a value" you mean into a number, then you can just change the format of that cell to "Number" instead of "Date." For instance, 8/12/2014 as a Number is equal to 41863. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Could you tolerate specifying the renewal type in months?

Comment: Yes months should be fine. I can work around that. What i mean by value is that how does excel hold the value of an arbitrary month? Not  01/01/14 into a numerical value. I suppose converting 02/01/14 into a numerical value and subtracting 01/01/14 from it would give me what i have in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Excel stores dates as floating point numbers. They advance by 1 each day and the fractional part holds the day fraction, e.g. 0.5 is midday. The exact value **is** user-configurable between 1900 and 1904 origins which can complicate things. Note that in the 1900 origin, date 60 (corresponding to the non-existent date 29-Feb-1900) is defined. Leap seconds are not implemented.]

If you can tolerate the second column being integral months, then use the `EDATE` function.

For example, if your table is orientated on cell `A1`, use

`=EDATE(A2, B2)` in cell `C2` and copy downwards.

Comment: Yup, during a 3am debugging session I'd thank myself for using a simple formula!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Vlookup in the third column which should point to a table which has conversion of 1 year/6mos into days. (365,180, ect). Then just add that vlookup to the original date.

So

```
   `TblDate
 Lookup Days
 1mo    30
 ..     ..`

=VLOOKUP(B1,TblDate,2,FALSE)+A1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("year",B2)),DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+LEFT(B2,1),DAY(A2)),DATE(YEAR(A2)+LEFT(B2,1),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to convert your second column into pure month format, using Excel:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2,"*Year*"),(TRIM(LEFT(B2,2)))*12,IF(COUNTIF(B2,"*Month*"),TRIM(LEFT(B2,2)),NA()))
```

This can then be used with `EDATE()`. For example, lets say that the above code is in cell C2, it would produce `12`. Then, you could in cell D2, you could put

```
EDATE(A2,C2)
```

in there. The code works for anything between 1 month and 99 years and doesn't care whether the first number is one or two digits and whether the word is month, months, year or years - it will work with all of it, as `TRIM()` removes whitespace (thus allowing for one character and a space or two characters) and `*` is a wildcard (hence allowing `x years` or `xz year`).

For `EDATE` to work you need to make sure the number format is set to date type.

Note: an extra cell for the months will be needed - so it might require a little rearranging, but using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or copy cells tool in the bottom right of a selected cell will easily copy it, and for each one it will automatically convert it.

Comment: Would upvote this if i could. Useful additional insight on implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In **D2** enter:

```
=--MID(B2,1,FIND(" ",B2))
```

and copy down

In **E2** enter:

```
=MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2)+1,1)
```

and copy down

Finally in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(E2="Y",DATE(YEAR(A2)+D2,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+D2,DAY(A2)))
```

Format **C2** as *Date* and copy down.  For example:

.

.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

create a new column and type in the formaula box

```
 =B2+1095
```

to get your renewal date

1 year is 365
2 years is 730
3 years is 1095
and so on and so forth.

this was the most simple way and worked for me!